# Removing grain from the cob

Tags: word-choice

Please let me know: Is there any specific word for removing grain from the cob?

Also, is there a proper word for its outer covering?

Answer (score 7):

The expression you are looking for is to ***[shell](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shell) cobs:***

> - to remove peas, nuts, etc. from their shells or their natural covering.

***[Corn sheller](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corn_sheller)***:

> - is a hand-held device or a piece of machinery to shell corn kernels of the cob for feeding to livestock or for other uses.

The outer green cover is called "***[husk](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/husk)***":

> - the dry external covering of certain fruits or seeds, especially of an ear of corn.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On the farm I grew up on in PA we called removing the outer husks from the cob husking and removing the hard corn from the cob shucking.

Comment: We, too, always called removing the husk *husking* and removing the dried kernels from the cob to feed animals *shucking*. The two are totally different.